# A nuclear fusion generating cart

Tags: nuclear-physics, hydrogen, fusion, nuclear-engineering

In an unrealistic thought experiment, suppose I had a $100$ meter track with a cart ontop that had a "pocket" on the front of the cart. Suppose further that this track and cart were in a room of hydrogen gas at 1atm.

How quickly would I need to accelerate the cart down the track so that by the end the compressed and heated hydrogen gas in the front "pocket" of the cart has fused together (i.e. the cart has caused a nuclear fusion reaction)?

Comment: Welcome user918####. Please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance paying particular attention to the [ask] section. You'll find that you are expected to show your own researches into the topic when posting. Oh, and obligatory [xkcd what-if](https://what-if.xkcd.com/1/) - relativistic baseball.

Answer (score 0):

> How quickly would I need to accelerate the cart down the track so that
> by the end the compressed and heated hydrogen gas in the front
> "pocket" of the cart has fused together (i.e. the cart has caused a
> nuclear fusion reaction)?

I believe no amount of speed will suffice.

The problem is that the compression takes place at the speed of sound in the substance, which in this case is hydrogen gas, so about four times the speed of sound in air. As the cart moves the gas will be compressed and heat up, but this will cause it to radiate the energy back out. This will occur much faster than the amount of hydrogen you can cram back onto the front. You might reach thousands of degrees, but not the ~100 million you need.